# "The centre of positive and the centre of negative coincide" What does that mean?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I'm doing AS level chemistry right now and my teacher told us that when a molecule is non polar , the centre of positive and the centre of negative coincide , I don't really get what he means by that .

Comment: Hi Lia, did your teacher follow up with a diagram of what he meant? Or an example molecule? Please add that to your question. Thanks!

Comment: Well, he meant just that. Molecules consists of atoms, and atoms consists of even smaller things, many of them charged. Take all positive charges, find the center...

Answer (score 3):

Each molecule has negatively charged electrons, and positively charged nuclei.

If the centroid of the electrons' charges (electron probability density) is different than the centroid of the nuclear charges, then the molecule will have a permanent electric dipole moment.

Answer (score 1):

Several concepts matter to what your teacher meant (but didn't seem to explain well).

One is that bonds are formed when electrons are shared between atoms.

When the atoms involved in the bond are not the same, the electrons are not distributed entirely evenly. When this happens there is, effectively, a mismatch between the distribution of positive charges (from the protons in the atoms' nuclei) and the negative charges in the distribution of the electrons in the bond. The extent of the mismatch is dependent on the relative electronegativity of the atoms.

So a bond between carbon and oxygen, for example, has the distribution of electrons biased towards the oxygen. So in a compound like CO the electrons tend to be closer to the oxygen. The mismatch of positive and negative charges gives the molecule a small electrical dipole. This matters for its chemical behaviour and how it interacts with other molecules.

But the *shape* of the molecule matters as well, not just the polarity of the bonds. So CO2, a linear molecule with two relatively polar bonds is not a polar molecule. This is because the two bonds are pointing in opposite directions so the *net* distribution of charge in each cancels out. The *overall* distribution of electrons and protons in the molecule now coincide with the centre of the molecule, giving it no net dipole moment. This, I think, is what your teacher means.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the molecules have two atoms of different electronegativities (ability to attract the bond pair of electrons); therefore this causes one atom nuclei to become surrounded by more electrons than the other atoms nuclei. This causes both the atoms positive and negative charges to not coincide.